# Troubleshooting Upload Errors for CSV File Conversion and MySQL Upload

Tags: types, error-handling, upload, sqldatatypes

[uploading data into MySQL with the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEDHG.png)post converting a file to CSV in Excel, many upload error messages are received while uploading the file to MySQL. Is it feasible to upload this data using the VARCHAR datatype and convert it post-upload?

I tried switching the datatype to timestamp and even datetime datatype, but the problem persists, despite the fact that the data has been correctly filtered in Excel to verify it is of the same datatype.
[The date in view in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb6vi.png)

Comment: Please consider posting a sample of a failing CSV row and the exact error message displayed for analysis.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the sample has been uploaded

Comment: Umar, Thanks for updating your question with error message and sample data. Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE `olist`,`olist_orders_dataset` for analysis.

Comment: This is the output: 'olist_orders_dataset', 'CREATE TABLE `olist_orders_dataset` (\n  `order_id` text,\n  `customer_id` text,\n  `order_status` text,\n  `order_purchase_timestamp` text,\n  `order_approved_at` text,\n  `order_delivered_carrier_date` text,\n  `order_delivered_customer_date` text,\n  `order_estimated_delivery_date` text\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

Comment: I successfully uploaded the olist_orders_dataset, but MySQL rejected it due to an incorrect format. When selecting the DateTime datatype, I encountered a caution sign with the format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S". However, my format was "dd-mm-yy h:mm", which MySQL doesn't recognize. So, MySQL warned me about potential recognition issues. I converted the format and selected DateTime, but only 6 out of 99442 rows were uploaded. As a workaround, I tried using the TEXT format, resulting in the successful upload of 99441 rows.

Comment: What you have posted is NOT the oucput of SHOW CREATE TABLE olist_orders_dataset.  Glad you have been successful with TEXT datatype.  You may find that storing date/time in TEXT datatyype is not helpful for your long-term goals.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if I should say MySQL is having trouble detecting datatypes or whatever; I tried uploading the same data to Google Sandbox, and the datatype for each was identified without issue. I'm going to give Postgrel a shot; if it works without a hitch, I'll probably use it for practice.

Comment: What does the date look like?  You may need a `STR_TO_DATE()` call.  Please provide the `LOAD` statement and a sample string.